# Ударение в Google fonts - частичный рендеринг в Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, шрифты, google-fonts

Я использую шрифт Open Sans (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans). Но когда слова в тексте имеет символ ударения, то Google Chrome отображает только часть слова, что идет после ударения. Интересно, что другие браузеры отображают такие тексты без проблем. Поэтому проблема только с указанным браузером.

Я понимаю, что каждый браузер имеет свой движок. Но все же, есть ли хорошие идеи, как решить или избежать эту проблему?

Сравнение:
[image: Comparative Google and Edge rendering]

```css
.open-sans-font {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700&amp;subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="open-sans-font">
 <p> філігра́нний — несамови́тий </p>
 <p> філігранний — несамовитий </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Судя по всему, с этим шрифтом — никак, в нём нет всех символов с диакритическими знаками. Теоретически, шрифт можно разобрать, добавить нужные глифы и тогда будет ок, но проще подобрать похожий шрифт, где все это уже сделано.

Answer (score 1):

Как оказалось, знак ударение относится не к кириллице, а к расширенной латинице (**latin-ext**).

И, на мой взгляд, при проблемах с поддержкой символов в шрифтах, лучше сразу обращаться к **google web fonts API** с параметром **text=**. В моем случае:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700&text=АБВГҐДЕЄЖЗИІЇЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЬЮЯабвгґдеєжзиіїйклмнопрстуфхцчшщьюя́" rel="stylesheet">
```